# save state and value of radio button

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

in the main activity i have radio buttons , in the method public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) i associate each radio button selected with a value, so i have two variables a and b, after that i click on the button bton i have according to the method ajouter, a and b values into database.Until now everything is okey, i decide to use OnResume and OnPause methods to save the state of activity, so when i return to the activity i see that the radio buttons are selected, the problem comes when i click on button to save info , i get 0 as value for a and b in database instead of values that i saw selected, and the weird thing is that when i click again on thoses radio buttons and after that on save button, i get  the right values ! My question here is how to make values of a and b without clicking again on the selected Radio Buttons ?

```
    public class ActivityUn extends Activity {
        public void  ajouter(View v) {
          db.open();               
          db.insertMENAGE(a,b);                   
          db.close();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données Enregistrées",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } 

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_un);       

         Button bton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ajoutUn);
         bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

          @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                   ajouter(v);                                            }
         });

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.rm_13_1:
                    if (checked)
                          a=1;
                        break;
                case R.id.rm_13_2:
                    if (checked)
                        a=2;
                        break;

                case R.id.rm_14_1:
                    if (checked)
                        b=1;

                    break;
                case R.id.rm_14_2:
                    if (checked)
                        b=2;
                       break;
                case R.id.rm_14_3:
                    if (checked)
                        b=3;
                    findViewById
                    break;
                case R.id.rm_14_4:
                    if (checked)
                        b=4;
                          break;
  }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs3 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
        MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs3.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("questionA", rm_13_1.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionB", rm_13_2.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionC", rm_14_1.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionD", rm_14_2.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionE", rm_14_3.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs3 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
    rm_13_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_13_1);
    rm_13_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_13_2);
    rm_14_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_1);
    rm_14_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_2);
    rm_14_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_2);
    Boolean rm_13_1A = false;
    Boolean rm_13_2A = false;
    Boolean rm_14_1A = false;
    Boolean rm_14_2A = false;
    Boolean rm_14_3A = false;
    rm_13_1A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionA", false);
    rm_13_2A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionB", false);
    rm_14_1A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionC", false);
    rm_14_2A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionD", false);
    rm_14_3A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionE", false);
    rm_13_1.setChecked(rm_13_1A);
    rm_13_2.setChecked(rm_13_2A);
    rm_14_1.setChecked(rm_14_1A);
    rm_14_2.setChecked(rm_14_2A);
    rm_14_3.setChecked(rm_14_3A);
}
```

Comment: i deployed many efforts without finding a solution, please help !

Comment: @Binghammar : is there a way  to resolve that ??

Comment: How do you mean that the "value is null" ?

Comment: i did associate each radio with a value,then i save value to database, the issue is the value is not there !!!

Comment: visually , the radio button is selected, but the value that it represents is absent, do you have idea why ?

Comment: Does the isChecked method give you back the correct value?

Comment: yes, it returns the correct value, but when i use it to store it in database i don't find it !!!

Comment: Is it not in the database at all, or is it stored with a null value?

Comment: Actually what do you put in the database ? if a radio button is checked ? where is the code that puts in the databse ? does onPause run ?

Comment: @ Vaibhav Aggarwal: yes it is stored with null value.

Comment: @ Mr_and_Mrs_D : i did edit my question, the code that's put values in the database is in oncreate, yes onPause run.

Comment: Go you really write code like that ? With no formatting at all ? Format your code

Comment: do you have idea about solution !!! i would be grateful :)

Comment: Format you code and try to explain what you want instead of asking the same question 2 times - if you do what people tell you you will have an answer. But if you post this code like that with no formatting and it is not clear what you ask you will NEVER get answer. Are you using eclipse ? If yes hit ctlr+shift+F

Comment: yes, i will do what you want, thanks for (ctlr+shift+F), i will explain more what is the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons should only exist in a radio button group. The characteristics of radio buttons is that only one in a group can be selected at a time. If a user selects C then all the other radio buttons become deselected (Think of a multiple choice question. You can only select one answer) If you're looking to have multiple options selected, look into android's [CheckBox view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for responding, what you said is correct and i know it,but the issue here is about how to get the values of radio button in OnResume method, without clicking on them again, as i explained i see the radio button selected but when i click on save button i don't get the value which is it the variable a for example

Comment: i think the problem is how i make the method public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) get recognized in OnResume !!

Comment: so when i click on save button automatically the values of a and b take the values specified in onRadioButtonClicked, that is what i am looking for , thanks again :)